# how to render things in different parts of a jsf structure with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, xpath

The concise version of the question I have is this:
How do I in response of a blur event on a

```
<h:inputText>
```

get the same value to show in a

```
<h:outputText>
```

located outside the scope of the inputText field.

The inputtext field has the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="form:j_idt40:src_table:0:j_idt137"]
```

The outputtext is located here:

```
//*[@id="form:j_idt40:target_table:0:target_id"]
```

I am using primefaces datatable and the two paths are located in two separate datatables

The jsf code for the input field is the following:

```
<p:dataTable id="src_table">
    <p:column id="src_id" headerText="srcHeader">
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.myAttribute}">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="src_id WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE?" ></f:ajax>
        </h:inputText>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

and the code for the output is the following

```
<p:dataTable id="target_table">
    <p:column headerText="TargetHeader">
        <h:outputText id="target_id" value="#{bean.myAttribute}" />
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

i have tried several paths on the WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE? placeholder but I can't seem to get it right. They have all ended up throwing faces exceptions like the following:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':target_id' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt137
```

this was of course when I replaced WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE? with :target_id

I have also tried:

```
form:j_idt40:target_table:0:target_id, 

:form:j_idt40:target_table:0:target_id
```

but no luck.

Can anyone help with my understanding of xpath or maybe even f:ajax and rendering specific parts of a view?

Comment: man, I don't know if that is possible with plain JSF... Can't you just render the entire `target_table`?

Comment: @elias yes that would suffice, any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Using `render="src_id :form:target_table"` in that f:ajax should suffice.

Comment: That almost did it. I needed the full path :form:j_idt40:target_table

Comment: Cool, glad you solved it! :)

Answer (score 1):

> *Can anyone help with my understanding of xpath*

JSF doesn't use Xpath in `<f:ajax>` at all. It just expects a relative or absolute client ID. This is in detail explained in [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762).

You should only change the component represented by the autogenerated ID `j_idt40` to have a fixed ID set, otherwise it would break again when you add or remove a component in the view later.